# TV series or movie about intern or new employee in a lab with monsters or mutants

Tags: story-identification, humor

I have a very vague recollection of a story involving a new female employee or intern in a lab setting. She seemed inexperienced and <strike>somewhat</strike> overwhelmed. The lab is performing experiments or possibly interrogating mutants, monsters, aliens, or a combination thereof. The environment was minimalistic and ambiently white, as to be expected from such a setting.

I kind of remember the camera's POV set behind a glass panel, as one of the creatures exploded at one time, splattering all over the glass panel. The whole scene was a static shot, focusing mainly on the female character. There were other human characters, but they *might* have been off-screen voices.

This was possibly a trailer for a movie or web/TV show which I likely have seen on YouTube, some time before 2010. The production *might* have ultimately been cancelled before release. I have a feeling this was some kind of sit-com.

**Addendum:** I want to say the scene was a job interview. While the interviewer/s are conversing with the candidate, mayhem occurs either because the creatures escape and are causing mayhem, and/or because experiments on the creatures go haywire. They try to pretend like it's no big deal and try to ignore the situation, but the madness is overwhelming.

Comment: Reminds me of Cabin in the Woods. Or possibly Buffy.

Comment: I went and watched a trailer for Cabin in the Woods, and it really doesn't give off the same feeling to what I remembered. Definitely not Buffy either. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Valorum It does sound a lot like a Joss Whedon idea but I don’t recognize the details.

Comment: Does not event nearly fit all of your points but reminds me of https://sanctuary.fandom.com/de/wiki/Amanda_Tapping with Amanda Tapping. The male protagonist is at the beginning introduced to the secret world. And I think in one episode there is someone exploding behind a window.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may have been [*The Pilot Episode Sanction*,](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2ivmq1) S01E01 of the cult classic *The Middleman*.  In the opening scene, the main character (Wendy Watson, played by the criminally underemployed Natalie Morales) is working as a temp receptionist at "AND Industries" (motto:  "We scramble your DNA".)  Her desk is in front of a window onto a modern-looking white & stainless-steel laboratory, and she has her back turned to it.

[image]

However, lights start flashing in the laboratory and things quickly go wrong.  Wendy does not notice anything going wrong until a genetic abomination bursts through the glass wall behind her.

[image]

[image]

This doesn't quite match all of the details you mention, but here's what does match:

> a new female employee or intern in a lab setting. She seemed inexperienced ...
> I want to say the scene was a job interview. While the interviewer/s are conversing with the candidate, mayhem occurs either because the creatures escape and are causing mayhem, and/or because experiments on the creatures go haywire. They try to pretend like it's no big deal and try to ignore the situation, but the madness is overwhelming.

Wendy is a temp, and during the scene is talking with her mother on the phone about how "plenty of art school graduates get science jobs."  However, she's not being interviewed.  (She does talk to her temp coordinator in the next scene of the episode, though, so perhaps you conflated the two scenes.)  And she's unaware of the "madness" behind her until the creature breaks through the glass.

> one of the creatures exploded at one time, splattering all over the glass panel.

The creature shown above doesn't explode, but rather suddenly comes out of the smoke and hits the glass as something of a jump scare.

> The whole scene was a static shot, focusing mainly on the female character.

The shot isn't entirely static—there are some medium shots—but the scene does return again and again to the wide-angle shot shown above.

> The production might have ultimately been cancelled before release.

The show only ran for one season of 12 episodes.

> I have a feeling this was some kind of sit-com.

The show was an 40-minute show (one hour with commercials), but it was undeniably comedic.  Think *Doctor Who* or *Buffy the Vampire Slayer* but even more arch.  [The AV Club described it at the time](https://film.avclub.com/the-middleman-the-complete-series-1798206623) as what you'd get "[i]f Joss Whedon and Amy Sherman-Palladino collaborated on a secret-agent/science-fiction/superhero script".

Comment: Wonderfully written answer, I especially appreciated the screenshots and detailed analysis. Thanks so much! Bounty will be allocated as soon as I'm allowed to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The description is somewhat similar to a British TV miniseries called *Chimera* (1991), also released in heavily edited form as *Monkey Boy*. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimera_(TV_series)) [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101577/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_5)

A nurse gets a new job at a fertility clinic. The clinic is actually a cover for a genetic research lab. They are creating human/ape hybrids. One of their experiments escapes and brutally murders the staff of the lab, then flees to roam the countryside.

It isn't a sitcom, it's a horror/ drama, but a short clip of it might appear bad/ funny.

I haven't seen it since its original broadcast. I don't recall if there was an interview scene, but she was certainly starting a new job, and was inexperienced/ overwhelmed.